# rename TFS 2018 U2 project and remove legacy alias

Tags: tfs

I am scripting a mass rename of ~100 TFS 2018 U2 projects by using the REST api, as a setup event to the project deletion that will occur in 2 weeks.

So, I'm renaming ~100 projects from **foobar** to TODELETE-**foobar**.

The rename is going great using the PATCH against /_apis/projects/$($project)?api-version=4.1, but I'd like to be able to get rid of the automatically created alias that lets TFSCOLLECTIONURL/**foobar** redirect to TFSCOLLECTIONURL/TODELETE-**foobar**

Nobody should be using these old projects, and getting rid of the redirect will help me ensure that they're not - this helps me cover employees that ignore my notifications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an X/Y problem. You have a problem:

#### People shouldn't be using legacy projects that are scheduled for deletion.

Your solution:

#### Break any existing links to the projects that shouldn't be in use.

However, as you're seeing, that's not an effective way to manage the problem, because people ignore or otherwise miss notifications.

The correct solution to your problem is a lot simpler and removes the possibility for someone to miss the memo that they shouldn't be using a project:

#### Make projects that shouldn't be used anymore read-only.

Bonus points: Put a link on the project's homepage via a README.md file that points to the place they **should** be working.

Comment: thx - suggestions on marking ~100 projects as read only? because my contacts at Microsoft didn't have an easy way.

Comment: @kkost REST APIs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1

Comment: I took a stab at it, and our ~100 projects are so different that there's no "easy" button here, whereas removing an alias feels very doable.

Thanks for the time - I'll work with my Microsoft TAM to see if they have any ideas here.

Comment: I mean, you'll have to dig through some REST APIs, but basically, for each project: 1) Create a new group "Read Only". 2) Add that group at the appropriate scopes with "Deny" permissions on 3) Look up the SID of the "Contributors" (or Project Valid Users, or both) group. 4) Add the group(s) to the "Read Only" group. The process is exactly the same for every project and can be scripted.

Comment: What about TFVC with different security at different sections of the tree, and inheritance off? Wouldn't that require a complete traversal of the source tree? While scriptable, that feels like a heck of a lot more work than worth, especially compared to removing a single alias per project.